# Getting return value from angular custom pipe before service return value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-pipe

I am trying to create a custom pipe for getting likes on particular post, it has a service which connects to database and pull all likes related to particular post, but when i try to run in my code, i am getting return value before the getting response from service, i know i should wait for the response but not sure how to do that.. please help me resolve this issue.

**HTML page**

```
 <a [ngClass]="{'like': toggle, 'dislike': !toggle}" (click)="addremovecomment($event, mainpost)" class="float-right btn-sm text-black btn mr-1 dislike"><span><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: dislike;"></i></span><label class="ml-1" id="lbl{{mainpost.id}}">{{mainpost | like }}</label></a>
```

**Service**

```
      getalllikes(post: MainPost): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + 'GetLikes', post);
  }
```

**Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { MainPost } from '../_models';
import { LikesService } from '../_services';
import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Pipe({
  name: 'like'
})
export class LikePipe implements PipeTransform {
  postlikes = 0;
  constructor(private likeservice: LikesService) {

  }
   transform(post: MainPost, ...args: any[]): any {
    const UserId = localStorage.getItem('UserId');
    this.getlikes(post);
    if (this.postlikes === 0) {
      return '0 Likes';
      } else {
      return this.postlikes + ' Likes';
      }
  }
   getlikes(post: any) {
    this.likeservice.getalllikes(post).subscribe(data => {
      console.log();
      // likes = data;
      this.postlikes = data;
    }, (err: any) => console.error(err));

  }

}
```

Comment: A pipe is not a good choice for what you want. Pipes should really be pure functions. You can just async subscribe to the service directly in your template..

Comment: @MikeOne thanks for the response, i am looping through all the posts from database, on page load i want to get how many likes are added to a particular post and also want to know if the current user have already liked the post, for the same reason i am using pipe, if not pipe please let me know what is the best approach in angular to do this

Comment: Are the likes available on the post?

Comment: yes, likes are displayed on the post(on HTML page), and in database likes are stored in different table.

Comment: Do the http call in `ngOnInit()` of your component and within the subscription, set the property that you bind in the template to the result of the http call. Basically move the code from your pipe to your component.

Comment: i believe then there is no option for running this code in pipe.

Comment: You could return the observable from the pipe. That is totally possible. Then you would chain the `async` pipe directly after it. `mainpost | like | async`. But you have to fix both `transform and `getLikes` in your pipe because they are completely wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I think that it is a best practice to keep the view logic inside a pipe, you can handle the total amount of likes to each post with the help of `Observables`, the `transform` method should be returning `Subject<T>`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'like'
})
export class LikePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private likeService: LikeService) {} 

  transform(id: number) : Subject<Object> {
    let likeSubject = new Subject<string>();

    this.likeService.getAllLikes(id)
    .subscribe(
      (posts: number) => {
        let message = "";
        if (posts == 0)
          message = "No Likes"
        else
          message = posts.toString() + " Likes"          

        likeSubject.next(message);
    });
    return likeSubject;    
  }
}
```

You will have to tell angular to resolve it with the `async` keyword:

```
<span>Post1 {{ ( id | like ) | async}}</span>
<hr>
<span>Post2 {{ ( id2 | like ) | async}}</span>
```

Here is a full working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bdbbem) app with your issue.

Comment: Thanks the above snippet will work.It saves some time